# Convergence in distribution. Why continuous points are the right set to look at?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

We define convergence in distribution where $$ is continuous. I understand why requiring convergence at every point is too strong. I just lack intuition why do we look at the continuous points of $F$. We could have defined the convergence on a smaller set/relaxed condition. Requiring $F_n \to F$ at all continuous points is still relatively strong so what does it buy us?

Answer (score 0):

Well, requiring the cdfs to converge at more places is "too strong" of a condition.

As an illustrative example, consider (constant) random variables $X_n=\frac{1}{n}$. This converges almost surely to the random variable $X=0$. But if you require the distribution functions to converge for all $x\in\mathbb R$ (in particular, at the discontinuity point $x=0$) then it would no longer be true that $X_n\stackrel{\mathcal D}{\to}X$!

So under this new definition, you can no longer say a.s. convergence $\implies$ weak convergence.